# A coin is tossed 1000 times and the result is stored as a string. Let x be the expected number of times the pattern TT occurs in the string. find x.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, problem-solving

A fair coin is tossed 1000 times and the result is stored as a string. Let x be the expected number of times the pattern TT occurs in the string. Find x.

i thought to first find total possible cases which equals 2^1000 . after that i thought to merge two TT together and place it at any of 999 places and remaining 998 can be placed in 2^998 ways. but it does not work. kindly looking for help to tackle such problem.

Comment: Apply linearity of expectation writing $X=X_1+\cdots+X_{999}$ where $X_i=1$ if T is on the spots $i,i+1$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @drhab; $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ aren't independent, so LoE doesn't apply.

Comment: @JMP For LoE you just don't need indepence. Unfortunately it is a wide spread misunderstanding that it should  be needed.

Comment: Does "...HTTTTH..." counts as 0, 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: See also [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) which contains a proof of the assertion in the comment of @drhab.

Comment: @Elmex80s The problem is greatly simplified if your example counts as 3 occurrences.  That interpretation is consistent with the answer of tommik.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with a smaller sample of coin tosses: i.e. $n=4$ and realize that you have 12 possible TT patterns on 16 total elementary 4-tuples.

Using @dhrab hint you have that your expectation is

$$\frac{1}{4}\times 3=\frac{12}{16}$$

Thus in your example you fine

$$\frac{1}{4}\times 999=\frac{999}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

We throw $k$ tails first, for $k-1$ TT's (typically $k-1=0$).

After that, we throw a 'super-coin', which throws $a>0$ heads and then $b>0$ tails, contributing $b-1$ TT's.

This coin is thrown until $k+A+B\ge1000$.

The expected number of heads thrown by the supercoin is $\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2$, and the same for tails.

Therefore the supercoin typically throws HHTT, (and then starts with H again), which is $1$ TT per throw (which is the same as throwing $4$ single coins).

Therefore we throw the supercoin $250$ times and get $250$ TT's, which is $\frac14$.

Comment: Are you sure?  Are you disagreeing with the answer of tommik?  Since Linearity of Expectation doesn't require independent events, and since you have $999$ events, each of which has a $(1/4)$ chance of occurring, it seems that tommik's answer is correct.  What am I missing?

Comment: @user2661923: you are missing nothing! My answer is correct. If you want to verify it, simply use a smaller number of tosses; 4 as in the following table. As you can see you have 12 TT patterns on 16 elementary events, that is Expected #TT$=12/16=3/4$
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfyGs.jpg

Comment: @user2661923; just a typo..

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line between any adjacent letters that are equal. In each of the $999$ space between letters the probability of line being drawn is $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore the expected number of lines is $\frac{999}{2}$. Because of symmetry, the expected number of lines between $TT$ is half of this; $\frac{999}{4}$